# How to detect when user is speaking into microphone and when not, using HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am working on a web application where I need to present user with the list of available microphones so that they can choose their preferred one and test that (like how google meet allows testing of mic, or any other app of that nature)

I am able to present list of attached devices using
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})`

Now when a user selects a microphone I want to detect when the user is speaking and when not, so that I can show some visual clue.

This is where I need help:

```
const constraints = { audio: { deviceId: { exact: selectedDeviceId } } };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => {


          // What should I do here with incoming stream? 
          // So that I can react to the input coming from microphone
          // Can I make use of any stream event and check for some condition in the handler? to detect when user is speaking
          // If there is no such event, what are my options?


      })
      .catch(function handleError(error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702721/how-to-get-microphone-volume-using-audioworklet